# Outlook all day, week long appt shows as 2 days

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

So, and I have no idea when this started, our Outlook versions above 2007 show appoints that span 1 week as only 2 days in the month view. There should be a "bar" across the entire week, but I only see that if I switch to the day view. So I want to go back to one box that spans the entire week, used to show up like that.

I have changed the view, checked for a formatting issue, deleted and recreated appointments to no avail. I simply cannot get the bar to span the full week in month view.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: I have changed the view, checked for a formatting issue, deleted and recreated appointments to no avail. I simply cannot get the bar to span the full week in month view.

Comment: Well...I fixed it. Not sure how. I changed a bunch to end a day earlier and then they showed as they used to. Then I changed another one and ALL appointments going forward changed without my involvement.